# Printing numeric values < NF in awk?

Tags: awk

I ran a bunch of tests using pgbench, logging the results:

```
run-params: 1 1 1
transaction type: SELECT only
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 1
number of threads: 1
duration: 90 s
number of transactions actually processed: 280465
tps = 3116.254233 (including connections establishing)
tps = 3116.936248 (excluding connections establishing)

run-params: 1 1 2
transaction type: SELECT only
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 1
number of threads: 1
duration: 90 s
number of transactions actually processed: 505943
tps = 5621.570463 (including connections establishing)
tps = 5622.811538 (excluding connections establishing)

run-params: 10000 10 3
transaction type: SELECT only
scaling factor: 10000
query mode: simple
number of clients: 10
number of threads: 1
duration: 90 s
number of transactions actually processed: 10
tps = 0.012268 (including connections establishing)
tps = 0.012270 (excluding connections establishing)
```

I want to extract the values for graphing. Trying to learn AWK at the same time. Here's my AWK program:

```
/run-params/      { scaling = $2 ; clients = $3 ; attempt = $4 }
/^tps.*excluding/ { print $scaling "," $clients "," $attempt "," $3 }
```

When I run that, I get the following output:

```
$ awk -f b.awk -- b.log 
tps,tps,tps,3116.936248
tps,tps,=,5622.811538
,,0.012270,0.012270
```

Which is not what I want.

I understand when `scaling = 1`, the 1 references field 1, which in this case happens to be tps. When scaling = 10000, because there aren't 10000 fields on the line, then null is returned. I did try assigning scaling and friends using `"" $2`, to no avail.

How does one use / report numeric values in a subsequent action block?

Comment: awk does not refer to variables with `$`, if you change `$scaling "," $clients "," $attempt` into `scaling "," clients "," attempt` it should work as you want.

Comment: Here's the code: `awk '/run-params/ { scaling=$2; clients=$3; attempt = $4 } /^tps.*excluding/ { print scaling, clients, attempt, $3 }' OFS="," file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drop the `$` in front of `scaling`, etc. That is, `scaling` is a variable reference, `$scaling` is a field reference.

Comment: Didn't you see Thor's comment above, like 5 minutes ago?

Comment: @Steve It would have been better as an answer. And, no, I skipped past the comments to check the answers.

Comment: I agree, it should have been an answer. But you should really read the question, comments and answers before posting. It's courteous too.

Comment: @steve I briefly scanned the comments, checked that there was nothing looking like a correct answer and filed one.